# Agile Web Development with Rails Chap8:Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session, token

I have completed chapter 7 successfully so far but now am stucked at Chapter 8: Sessions

I m using rails version 2.3.2

I am following the instructions and code as written in the book but It is showing me the error of Token Authentiction Failed when i refresh store.rb to see the cart.

how can i resolve this problem? i want to know from where i can get this token n where n in which file i have to put it?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? What edition of the book?

Comment: i m using 2.3.2 rails version

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked into the book's [errata](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/errata)?

Also, you could try to verify that you did not make any mistakes by checking if the [original code](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/source_code) runs in your environment.

Be aware though, that in order to use rails' RequestForgeryProtection, your form has to include the token.

Comment: yes i have checked my complete before this session code it all work properly but when i start coding for session it show me this error

u r right that there is some problem in RequestForgeryProtection when as per code in book it is also not working though i m using rails2.3 n it is written in the book that with this version of rails secrets r not supported and needed but i tried it but its also not working

Comment: i want to know where i have to put the token exactly n where from i get the real exact token number?